# How to search for a value being in a known range in mySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, range

Let's say I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE venue = "1" OR venue = "10"
```

That's great, works fine.  But let's say I have a list of 50 venue numbers.  Is there an easy way to do this where I don't have to write out 50 different ORs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ["IN"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/select.html) instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE venue IN (1, 12, 23, ... 150)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE venue IN ('1','10')
```

Best answer would be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE venue IN @myVar
```

Where @myVar is a list set in the query,

Comment: You can't set IN parameters as prepared statement variable. You certainly can append `@myVar` to query text, but then I'm not sure why that would be "best".

Comment: Well, if this was being called from an application, having a variable in the query that you can set is better than putting it inline, thats all I am trying to say.  If your running the query in query analyser or SQLYog, then the way you wrote it would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IN` keyword:  `... WHERE venue IN (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE venue in ('1', '10')
```

I know it works in Oracle.  "in" operator is probably part of standard SQL?  Dunno.

edit: changed double to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure if MySQL supports this...*

Use the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE venue BETWEEN '1' and '50';
```

Although you may need to be more explicit when dealing with character string 
datatypes:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE venue BETWEEN '1' and '9'
     OR venue BETWEEN '10' and 50';
```

Of course, `BETWEEN` won't help if your list of numbers are non-contiguous.